# TinkerPop Gremlin with Chinese

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to query for vertices which contain Chinese characters.

I'm executing a groovy script via `$gremlin.sh -e test.groovy`

`println g.V("丁壽全").next()`

When trying to look up a vertex, which consists only of ASCII, it's found.

How should I encode the strings?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gremlin-server connected to Stardog. A solution was to:

```
  import com.complexible.stardog.graph.ids.GraphIRI
  ... gremlin stardog plugin init...
  iri = new GraphIRI("http://someuri" + "chinese string")
  individual = g.V(iri)
```